# Не получается подключиться к irc с помощью fsockopen

Tags: php, irc

Здравствуйте, уважаемый кодеры.
Пожалуйста, помогите найти ошибку в PHP-коде.

```
<?php 
set_time_limit(0); 

$chan = "main"; 
$server = "galaxy.mobstudio.ru"; 
$port = 6667; 
$nick = "29ept1rh9i";
$galaxy = ":ru IDENT 34 -1 4030 :GALA";
$user = "13908660 nrhsk81w 0";
$his = "13908660 nrhsk81w";

$socket = fsockopen("$server", $port); 
fputs($socket,"$galaxy\n"); 
fputs($socket,"RECOVER $nick\n"); 
fputs($socket,"USER $user\n")
fputs($socket,"JOIN ".$chan."\n");
fputs($socket,"ADDONS\n")
fputs($socket,"MYADDONS\n")
fputs($socket,"HISTORY $his\n") 

while(1) { 
    while($data = fgets($socket)) { 
            echo nl2br($data); 
            flush(); 

            $ex = explode(' ', $data); 
        $rawcmd = explode(':', $ex[3]); 
        $oneword = explode('<br>', $rawcmd); 
            $channel = $ex[2]; 
        $nicka = explode('@', $ex[0]); 
        $nickb = explode('!', $nicka[0]); 
        $nickc = explode(':', $nickb[0]); 

        $host = $nicka[1]; 
        $nick = $nickc[1]; 
            if($ex[0] == "PING"){ 
                fputs($socket, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\n"); 
            } 

        $args = NULL; for ($i = 4; $i < count($ex); $i++) { $args .= $ex[$i] . ' '; } 

            if ($rawcmd[1] == "!say") { 
                fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$chan." :".$args." \n"); 
            } 
        elseif ($rawcmd[1] == "!md5") { 
            fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$nick." :".md5($args)."\n"); 
        } 
        elseif ($rawcmd[1] == "!base64_encode") { 
            fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$nick." :".base64_encode($args)."\n"); 
        } 
        elseif ($rawcmd[1] == "!base64_decode") { 
            fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$nick." :".base64_decode($args)."\n"); 
        } 
        elseif ($rawcmd[1] == "!help") { 
            fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$nick." :йа лоло\n"); 
        } 
        elseif ($rawcmd[1] == "!about") { 
            fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$nick." :я мего лоло irc бот\n"); 
        } 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: А ошибка то в чем ?

Comment: я не знаю в чем.. у меня когда ошибка в коде, скрипт не открывается.. пишет "Удаленный сервер не найден". У меня просто свой хостинг стоит.  Знаю, что ошибка есть в коде..

Comment: Удаленный сервер не найден?
Сообщение такое же, как и по адресу http://fdsfewfsd.ru/ , например?
Видимо у вас проблема именно с доступом к хостингу, а не со скриптом.
например проблема с DNS, из-за свеже зареганного домена, или вообще весь сервак лежит

Comment: нет, нет, нет.. у меня все хорошо) просто хостер так сделал) когда в скрипте ошибка - то вот так вот, если нормально все - то скрипт работает. вот и написал сюда

Comment: @JavaBitz почему бы вам не поставить локальный сервер, неужели вы все ошибки таким образом вылавливать будете?

Comment: сервер у них тупит временно

Answer (score 2):

```
fputs($socket,"RECOVER $nick\n"); 
fputs($socket,"USER $user\n")
fputs($socket,"JOIN ".$chan."\n");
```

После "USER $usern") нету ";"

```
fputs($socket,"ADDONS\n")
fputs($socket,"MYADDONS\n")
fputs($socket,"HISTORY $his\n")
```

Аналогично

Comment: спасибо, позже попробую.. у тебя icq есть?

Comment: если синтаксические ошибки не вываливаются на страницу, то вероятно, если они вовсе не отключены или в другое место не перенаправлены, могут находиться в /var/log/apache2/error.log